# Gaming Questions of the Week #5

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion, blog, question-of-the-week

In an effort to try and keep the Question of the Week going, please submit your suggestions for this week!

### Sample Questions:

- First week's question - [Minecraft's World Size](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/minecrafts-world-size)
- Second weeks question - [Pokemon Missingno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/19638/10)
- Last week's top answer - [Does GLaDOS hate Atlas, the Blue Robot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20540/3015)
- Suggestions:

  - [Playing Portal before Portal 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/playing-portal-before-portal-2)
  - [Where is there “impossible geometry” in Portal 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20601/where-is-there-impossible-geometry-in-portal-2)
  - [Portal 2's Turret Symphony Song and Lyrics?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/portal-2s-turret-symphony-song-and-lyrics)

If you want to nominate either of the two sample questions for this week, post them as an answer. Feel free to nominate any questions (or answers) you feel are deserve it as well!

Comment: Portal 2 is the game of the moment, and I totally agree to choose one of these questions, even if is the second consecutive week.

Comment: Perhaps I'll write a blog post that just mixes together 'the best of' Portal 2 on Gaming.SE as a QotW then

Comment: The one about impossible geometry is my pick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fine with another Portal question, but I think this one might also make for an interesting blog entry.

[Other than being ethically correct, what are the benefits of playing with original game CDs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20973/other-than-being-ethically-correct-what-are-the-benefits-of-playing-with-original)

Comment: Care to write something about it yourself @Bwarner?

Comment: @Ivo I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 4):

I would be most in favor of [Playing Portal before Portal 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20975/playing-portal-before-portal-2) for two reasons:

1. If the same game is being spotlighted twice in a row, it would be nice if it were as approachable a question as possible for those who aren't currently playing.  (And a "how do I start playing?"-type question is about as approachable as you can get.)
2. It's the only one which doesn't contain spoilers.  Granted, the spoilers in the "impossible geometry" question are very subtle, but they *are* there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for [What's the goal of Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21553/whats-the-goal-of-minecraft-and-what-can-users-achieve-in-this-world/21558#21558)

Comment: Would you like to write a blog post about it yourself @fredly? Preferably mixing in some of our own questions to underpin the various points you mention

Comment: @Ivo Yeah sure, I'm heading over to chat now if you want to talk about it

Comment: [This got bloggified](http://gaming.blogoverflow.com/qotw/10-awesome-things-to-try-in-minecraft), thanks @fredley